# Until / do loop achieves desired effect but throws several syntax errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

The following bash script executes a second bash script and then waits to observe effects of the second script using `until / do`. This script is running on a RHEL7 server.

```
FILE=/sentinel_failover.sh
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
    OUTPUT=$("$FILE")
    echo $OUTPUT

    $counter=0
    $max_loop_count=30
    #Continue when no instances on this server are primary or the timeout has elapsed
    until (( $counter == $max_loop_count || $primary_byte_count == 0 ))
    do
      primary_byte_count=$(grep /etc/redis/redis.* -e port -e auth \
      | sed 's/.*\:port/redis-cli -p/' \
      | sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /' \
      | sed 's#\/etc\/redis\/redis.* "# -a #' \
      | sed -e 's/"/ --no-auth-warning info \| grep role/' \
      | sed -e 'N;s/  / /' \
      | source /dev/stdin \
      | grep master \
      | wc -c)
      sleep 1
      ((counter++))
    done

  if [[ $primary_byte_count -eq 0 ]]
  then
        exit 0
  else
        fail_step "Incomplete failover before reaching max loop count of 30 $max_loop_count"
  fi
```

The script achieves desired effect and I have verified this by echoing counter values at strategic locations, however the following errors are emitted upon first execution of the loop:

```
/test_script.sh: line 8: =0: command not found
/test_script.sh: line 9: =30: command not found
/test_script.sh: line 11: ((: == 30 ||  == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 30 ||  == 0 ")
```

How can I reconfigure the comparison or otherwise modify the script to resolve this?

Comment: Use Shellcheck to debug your shell scripts, as the Bash tag recommends.

Comment: Thank you!. Was not aware of this tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the value of a variable, you should only use the variable's name, without the `$`: `var=value` and not `$var=value`.

In your script, you have these two lines:

```
$counter=0
$max_loop_count=30
```

Those are giving you the syntax error, the shell doesn't recognize that as a variable assignment and is instead trying to execute them as commands. You can easily verify this by pasting into a terminal:

```
$ $counter=0
bash: =0: command not found
$ $max_loop_count=30
bash: =30: command not found
```

Since those lines aren't actually setting any value for the variable, this causes the next syntax error:

```
/test_script.sh: line 11: ((: == 30 ||  == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 30 ||  == 0 ")
```

This is because when you run this line:

```
until (( $counter == $max_loop_count || $primary_byte_count == 0 ))
```

None of the variables have a value, so your test becomes  `== 0`.

You can fix all three errors by correcting the variable assignments to:

```
counter=0
max_loop_count=30
```

Finally, please avoid using CAPITAL letters for your variables in shell files. The convention is to use CAPS for environment variables so using them for your own variables can lead to name collisions and hard to track bugs. It is generally good practice to always have your variables lower case.

Comment: Also, `primary_byte_count` is not initialized before the loop (it should presumably be set to something nonzero).

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, I mention that in the second point where I say that none of the variables has a value. That's one of them.